# Linux Bash IF service is running

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Below is a simple Powershell script on if a service is running or not

```
$service = 'Serenade'
if ($service.Status -ne 'Running')
{Start-Service -Name $service}
Else
{write-host 'Service already running'}
```

What is the equivalent in writing a Linux Bash script on if a service is running or not?

Comment: If you service is under systemd control, use `systemctl status SERVICE`.  If under init.d, you will have a "S*service" script which has a status option.

Comment: Can you write out script showing example?

Comment: I *could*, but not knowing what controls your services (systemd or init.d) and without specifics I would not create a generic script.  There are examples of each if you look around.  And you would not learn by just copy-paste code from here.

Comment: I'm using systemctl. Can you give me an example one with that?

Answer (score 0):

This would the equivalent in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

service_name="Serenade"

if systemctl is-active --quiet "$service_name.service" ; then
  echo "$service_name running"
else
  systemctl start "$service_name"
fi
```

Before you can execute it, you need to set the executable bit on the file:

```
chmod +x service_checker_file.sh
```

Now you can execute it:

```
./service_checker_file.sh
```